# Risks of changing the account MS SQL Servers run under

Tags: sql-server

I have a MS SQL Server 2008 R2 that was setup and is running under a "Virtual System Account" (`NT Service\MSSQLSERVER`).

The problem is, that MS SQL Server isn't able to do backups (from within SQL using `BACKUP DATABASE`) to a network share under this account type (it doesn't see any network shares).

Now, if I change the account to a local administrator account (yeah, security implications), what are the risks doing so? Will it "just work"? Is there any preparation do be done *before*? If it doesn't work, can I go back to make it work again?

> I don't want to integrate the server into Active Directory (for reasons). So running under a domain account isn't an option.

Comment: It should work fine, as long as the account you choose has network rights to the target.  Note: Don't just change the services' logins, use the SQL Configurator.  See this: [SQL Server service account Windows privileges and rights](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89701/sql-server-service-account-windows-privileges-and-rights)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! So _this_: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89715 "When changing any of the services for SQL Server, always use SSCM. Always. Period." and "use SQL Server Configuration Manager to change the service user account logons and no additional permissions should be required" - Ok. Cool.

Comment: For reference, here is the Microsoft doc talking about changing service account using SSCM https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#Anchor_1